# How to run mvn clean install command through pre-commit husky hooks on Windows?

Tags: windows, maven, intellij-idea, pre-commit-hook

Is there way to run mvn clean install command through pre-commit husky hooks on Windows without need to specify full path of maven like this

#!/bin/bash
./node_modules/pre-commit/hook

C:\idea2020.3\2020.3.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\mvn clean install

exit 0

I tried this link: https://gist.github.com/arnobroekhof/9454645
But it seems it works on Ubuntu not on windows.

Instead is there any other way to find maven path and execute the command?

Comment: You can also install yourself a Maven to any place and use it.

Comment: What is the purpose of running Maven within a pre-commit hook?